# Get only the top 10 results of Google Prediction instead of all results

Tags: google-prediction

I have implemented a model that maps the incoming data into one of 1000 categories (label) available. For each entry, the Google Prediction returns all categories in 1000. Is there any way to make the Google Prediction return, for example, only the 10 most important outcomes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can't get the top 10 on 1000.

If you **really** need to limited the number of result on the server side you can have your own server in the middle who "cleanup" the result for you.
Depending the size of your project, I recommend you Google App Engine. It will use Google Network who is very quick and have low latency.

From Google Prediction API webservice you can only limited to the most relevant category.
Using [Google API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/prediction/v1.6/prediction.hostedmodels.predict?project=344504343063&hostedModelName=job_training&fields=id%252Ckind%252CoutputLabel%252CoutputValue%252CselfLink&_h=9&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522input%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522csvInstance%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%255B%2522java%20developer%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%255D%250A%20%20%257D%250A%257D&) generate this kind of POST request:

> POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.6/projects/{YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER}/hostedmodels/job_training/predict?fields=id%2Ckind%2CoutputLabel%2CoutputValue%2CselfLink&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
>
> Content-Type:  application/json Authorization:  Bearer
>   ya29.AHES6ZQykLLg0ctjS1YYnxMEUn2kCi7OL4UZj4_-e92cuPfywxJatw
>   X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
>
> {"input":
>             {"csvInstance": [    "YOUR PREDICTION"   ]}
>   }

The URL request parameter "field" don't include "outputMulti" (all the other result)